# как получить значение по клику?

Tags: javascript, события, click

Есть такой объект:

```
var levelTimes = {
        guruHard : [10000, 10000, 10000],
        guruLow : [30000, 30000, 30000],
        guruMiddle : [20000, 20000, 20000],
        traineeHard : [10000, 10000, 10000],
        traineeLow : [30000, 30000, 30000],
        traineeMiddle : [20000, 20000, 20000]
    };
```

Как по клику из него получать значения ?

В зависимости от того на каком элементе кликнуть нужно получить определенный массив например levelTimes.guruHard или levelTimes.traineeMiddle и тд, а дальше оперировать этим массивом.

Вот пример кода:

```js
var level = document.getElementById('difficultyLevel')
var levelTimes = {
  guruHard: [10000, 10000, 10000],
  guruLow: [30000, 30000, 30000],
  guruMiddle: [20000, 20000, 20000],
  traineeHard: [10000, 10000, 10000],
  traineeLow: [30000, 30000, 30000],
  traineeMiddle: [20000, 20000, 20000]
};

level.onclick = function setLevelTimes(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  while (target != this) {
    if (target.className.split(' ')[1] == 'level') {
      var targetItem = camelize(target.innerText);

      console.log(targetItem);
      return;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  return targetItem;
}
console.log(levelTimes.targetItem); //здесь выдает undefined, а должен быть массив!

function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="difficultyLevel">
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Guru Hard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Guru Low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Guru Middle</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Trainee Hard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Trainee Low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Trainee Middle</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: в зависимости от того на каком элементе кликнуть нужно получить определенный массив например levelTimes.guruHard  или  levelTimes.traineeMiddle и тд, а дальше оперировать этим массивом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> console.log(levelTimes.targetItem); //здесь выдает undefined, а должен быть массив!

По этой строке :

код выполняется по очереди, как написан, то-есть так :

1. обьявляется переменная level
2. обьявляется обьект levelTimes
3. вешается событие клика
4. выводится в консоль свойство `targetItem` обьекта `levelTimes` (его нету, по-этому получаем `undefined`)

Можно сделать так :

```js
var level = document.getElementById('difficultyLevel');
var levelTimes = {
  guruHard: [10000, 10000, 10000],
  guruLow: [30000, 30000, 30000],
  guruMiddle: [20000, 20000, 20000],
  traineeHard: [10000, 10000, 10000],
  traineeLow: [30000, 30000, 30000],
  traineeMiddle: [20000, 20000, 20000]
};

level.onclick = function setLevelTimes(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('level')) {
    levelTimes.targetItem = levelTimes[camelize(e.target.innerText)];
    console.log(levelTimes.targetItem);
  }
}

function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="difficultyLevel">
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Guru Hard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Guru Low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Guru Middle</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Trainee Hard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Trainee Low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" href="#">Trainee Middle</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Структура html:

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="difficultyLevel">
    <a class="dropdown-item level" id="guruHard" href="#!">Guru Hard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" id="guruLow" href="#!">Guru Low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" id="guruMiddle" href="#!">Guru Middle</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" id="traineeHard" href="#!">Trainee Hard</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" id="traineeLow" href="#!">Trainee Low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item level" id="traineeMiddle" href="#!">Trainee Middle</a>
  </div>
```

> Код JS:

```
level.onclick = function setLevelTimes() {
  var target = event.target;

  if (target.className.split(' ')[1] == 'level') {  

        result = levelTimes[target.id];
        console.log('Переменная result: '+result); 

    } 
  return result;
}
```

> Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка простая, в объекте `levelTimes` не свойства `targetItem`. Возможно, если вы строку:

```
var targetItem = camelize(target.innerText);
```

заменете на

```
levelTime.targetItem = camelize(target.innerText);
```

========= Дополнение ==========
Если хотите сделать переменную глобальную объявляйте ее за прелелами функции(события). Также, после моего исправления у Вас такая же будет ошибка. Так как скрипт погружается моментально, а данные добавятся через время (когда сработает событие)

Comment: все равно выдает undefined, создал переменную var targetItem перед функцией и заменил то что вы написали, тогда просто targetItem == undefined a levelTimes.undefined ничего не даст(

Comment: >>>Ошибка простая, в объекте levelTimes не свойства targetItem
мне как раз не нужно чтобы targetItem был в объекте, мне надо, чтобы он подменялся нужным значением по которому кликнуть

Comment: вы бы более детально описали что именно вы хотите получить, так как лично меня например совсем сбил с толку этот странный цикл в обработке клика... (типа, клацаю сюда, вижу птичку, клацаю туда вижу слона)

Comment: в зависимости от сложности левела меняется время, мне нужно получить это время кликнув по нужному левелу, время передается в массиве

Comment: куда получить ? записать в обьект `levelTimes` в свойство под названием `targetItem` ?

Comment: @Даниил ну где ? где его нужно получить ? записать в обьект levelTimes  ?

Comment: @Даниил тысяча извинений, я чето подумал что вы и есть автор :)

Comment: нужно записать массив в отдельную переменную, кликнул на guruHard и чтобы в новой переменной(например levelTime) появился массив  [10000, 10000, 10000]

Comment: @Даниил id чего? дайте пожалуста пример простого кода

Comment: @Даниил по ходу то что нужно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68417/discussion-between--and-agafron).